# Ruby - weird behaviour after added to PATH

Tags: ruby, windows, rubyinstaller

I really don't understand what's the hell is going on.

It seems that Ruby is already in the PATH variable, but sometimes it work, sometimes - not. I tested it with `ruby -v`.

If I launch `cmd.exe` via "Run" command (`Win+R`), it will be opened in `C:\Users\John` directory. `ruby -v` will work there. Then, if I type `cd c:\`, and then type `ruby -v` - it still works. However, if I open explorer window, right click on drive C and select "Open CMD here" - `ruby -v` will not work!

```
'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command...
```

Another programs added to PATH, like Python and MultiMarkdown works OK. So, it seems some error with Ruby installation? I tried to reinstall it, but it doesn't helped.

Ruby+Devkit 2.4.4-2 (x86)

**Update based on comments**

Here is screenshot:

[image]

`C:\Ruby24\bin` is already added to both places. It is also shown if I type `path` in my `cmd.exe`.

**Update 2**

```
This is what I have in the 1st field in the screenshot above:

C:\Ruby24\bin;
C:\Python33;
C:\Python33\Scripts;
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Pandoc\;
C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm

-----

This is what I have in the 2nd field in the screenshot above
(and the same if I type "path" in my cmd.exe):

C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v5.4;
C:\Python33\;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;
C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;
C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;
C:\Ruby24\bin;
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Pandoc\;
C:\Python33\Scripts;
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Comment: Are you sure `ruby.exe` is in your path? It's worth checking manually.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I checked. I will update my question in a few minutes.

Comment: @tadman I added screenshot and some text info.

Comment: Screenshots are almost always the worst way to show this information. I can't scroll to see the rest of that string, for example. Can you copy-paste the exact text into an edit on your question? Can you also verify in the command-line that `PATH` is set correctly?

Comment: @tadman I added it to question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/445608/windows-7-open-command-window-here-not-getting-updated-path-variable

Comment: If you can run `C:\Ruby24\bin\ruby` then that should work and if it's not doing that I'm stumped.

Comment: And @johnc.j. as per the comments above, I don't actually know whether the ruby folder is in your `PATH`.  Have you tried checking its value from **inside the terminal**? This sounds like a bug with Windows not setting the `PATH` when clicking "open CMD here"; not really a bug in ruby at all.

Comment: @TomLord Thank you. Yes, reboot helped.

Comment: Move the Ruby entry to the top of each list, might hopefully solve problem. It searches in order of that list. Another file/folder in the other entries might have the name `ruby` and screwing it up. Although it appears it should be using the current user and not the system variable unless you running as admin, it is worth a try without any consequence.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 See previous comment. It was necessary to reboot. This question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @johnc.j. Oops, didn't see that, the comments weren't expanded :P